# Printing singly linked list ends the program abruptly

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here is my code, I am trying to have a program ask the user for some numbers then print them out. I have implemented the use of linked lists for my purpose. The program works but ends abruptly, I have no idea what to add or remove from the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
}ListNode;
void printList(ListNode *head);
int main()
{
    int n;
    ListNode *head = NULL;
    ListNode *temp = NULL;
    printf("Enter a value: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n != -1)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = head;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->item = n;
        printf("Enter a value: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%i\n", head->item);
        head = head->next;
    }
    free(head);
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter 3 numbes (e.g. 1, 2 and 3), it prints out 123 then ends the program abuptly. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: So your input is 1 2 3 and -1?

Comment: yes correct, i forgot to state that i have to enter -1 to end the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not set the next field of the last element to NULL:

```
temp->item = n;
temp->next = NULL;  // add this line
```

And when printing, `while (head != NULL)` will never hold as there is rubbish in head->next. So then you are trying to access arbitrary pointer which leads to crash.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Simple explaination!

Answer (score -1):

It ends because after it finishes printing you have `return 0;` which traditionally ends the program when it's encountered in `main()`

Also, you have a memory leak. Nothing is getting freed except NULL, which according to the man page, causes no action to be performed.

I just looked again. Another of your problems is that you never initialize head->next, so it's just some random garbage you get from a buffer overrun.

Comment: No the problem is that it crashes the program after it prints 123. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: What makes you think it's crashing?

Comment: Because i use CTRL+F5 on visual studio to stop the program from ending straightaway because it will ask me to press any button to end the program. It did not get to the part where it asks me to press any button.